# How to populate Oracle partition table

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, populate

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE TBIGP
(
IDPER NUMBER(6),
DESCRIZIONE VARCHAR2(50),
DINS DATE
)
PARTITION BY LIST (IDPER)
(
PARTITION P201201 VALUES(201201),
PARTITION P201202 VALUES(201202),
PARTITION P201203 VALUES(201203),
PARTITION P201204 VALUES(201204),
PARTITION P201205 VALUES(201205),
PARTITION P201206 VALUES(201206),
PARTITION P201207 VALUES(201207),
PARTITION P201208 VALUES(201208),
PARTITION P201209 VALUES(201209),
PARTITION P201210 VALUES(201210),
PARTITION P201211 VALUES(201211),
PARTITION P201212 VALUES(201212),
PARTITION P201301 VALUES(201301),
PARTITION P201302 VALUES(201302),
PARTITION P201303 VALUES(201303),
PARTITION P201304 VALUES(201304),
PARTITION P201305 VALUES(201305),
PARTITION P201306 VALUES(201306),
PARTITION P201307 VALUES(201307),
PARTITION P201308 VALUES(201308),
PARTITION P201309 VALUES(201309),
PARTITION P201310 VALUES(201310),
PARTITION P201311 VALUES(201311),
PARTITION P201312 VALUES(201312),
PARTITION OTHER VALUES(DEFAULT)
);
```

Now I want to populate the table in this way. Using some iterative procedure like *for*, *while* or *loop*, I would that every partition was composed by 500000 records. For precision, every partition have from 1 to 450000-500000 records, where the number of records is random (one partition can have 480000 records, another partition have 490000 or 450000 or 467890 records....).

Every 1000 records generated, I want to do a *commit*.

I don't know if it's clear. It's difficult for me to explain in english. Thank you.

**EDIT**

Something like this:

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..24
LOOP
j:=1
z:=dbms_random.value(450000,500000)
WHILE j<=z
INSERT INTO T_BIG_P_1
VALUES (i, 'description', TRUNC(SYSDATE + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,366))
IF MOD (j, 1000) = 0 THEN
COMMIT;
END IF;
j:=j+1;
END LOOP;
END;

exec DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('SH','T_BIG_P_1');
```

Comment: "populate" - where does your data come from? Another table, a file, a procedure?

Comment: Oracle version 11. I have to populate the table manually with a procedure. After the create I want do a plsql procedure with a loop to populate the table.

Comment: This seems quite an unusual use of the PARTITION mechanism - are you sure youw ant to 480000 rows with the value 201312 in a column called IDPER ?

Comment: @GregHNZ yes is only for excersise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple anonymous PL/SQL block should suit your needs:

```
DECLARE
  n INTEGER;
  idper INTEGER;
  s VARCHAR2(50);  
begin
  FOR year IN 2012..2013 LOOP
    FOR MONTH IN 1..12 LOOP
      idper := MONTH+(YEAR*100); 
      n := Dbms_Random.Value( low=>450000, high => 500000 );
      FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
        s := Dbms_Random.string('x',25)||' '||idper;
        INSERT INTO TBIGP (idper,DESCRIZIONE,DINS) VALUES (idper,s,SYSDATE); 
        IF Mod(i,1000) = 0 THEN
            COMMIT;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Note that this code can probably be further optimized by using the FORALL statement to benefit from bulk inserts.

Answer (score 1):

To insert data from a procedure into your table, you could use code that looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_filler  AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 500000 LOOP

    -- compute your idper, descrizione, dins and then insert into the table
    INSERT INTO tbigp (idper, descrizione, dins) VALUES (x, y, z);

    IF MOD(i, 10)=0 THEN
      dbms_application_info.set_module('my_filler', 'i='||i);
      COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END my_filler;
/
```

Having said that, this will be *very, very* slow. I wouldn't advice to

1. fill it with a procedure
2. commit after 1000 rows

Comment: See my edit.... it's something like this! In the IDPER column there are a sort of date of years 2012/13 partitioned by month... something like 201201, 201202, 201203 and so on. I want to insert 2 years in the column.

Comment: Are the partition names important or can you use interval partitioning?